# Postgres: Search by annotated/concatenated json values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a django model that uses postgres json column.

```py
class ClassName:
    json=JsonField()
```

This is the schema in the json field.

```
{
  'lev1': {
    'lev2': {
      first_name: 'Alex',
      last_name: 'Anderson',
      street: '242 Bell St,',
      city:'New York',
      state:'NY',
    }
}
```

Now I have this data, I have to filter it by with the user's full_name and full address.

I am looking for something like

```
ClassName.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat(F('lvl1__lvl2__first_name'), Value(' '),
                    F('lvl1__lvl2__last_name')),
    full_address=Concat(F('lvl1__lvl2__address'), Value(' '),
                        F('lvl1__lvl2__city'), Value(' '),
                        F('lvl1__lvl2__state'), Value(' '),
                        F('lvl1__lvl2__zipcode')),
).filter(full_name__icontains="Alex Anderson")
```

I have tried all different json functions, not able to get the right combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is an [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29769) in Django that prevents using JSON fields directly in `F` function... This prevents your code from working...

Solution for that is to embed raw SQL fragment in your code. Ugly, but that's all we've got.

```
TestJsonAnn.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat(
        RawSQL("(json->'lev1'->'lev2'->>'first_name')", ()),
        Value(' '),
        RawSQL("(json->'lev1'->'lev2'->>'last_name')", ())
    )
).filter(full_name__icontains="Alex Anderson")
```

Notice `->>` operator used at last extraction instead of `->`. This is required, because `->` will return data as a JSON object so your string will be additionally quoted, `->>` returns it as a string. For more about extracting fields in raw SQL, see [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)